# One plank of my PVC privacy fence came loose at the top.

Tags: fence, pvc

How can I get one plank of a PVC privacy fence back in place?  I'm not sure how it come out.  The rest of the fence is intact.  I can't bend it back into place.  I'm thinking heat would help but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: what kind of PVC privacy fence?  Maybe you can find it [here](http://www.homedepot.com/b/Lumber-Composites-Fencing-Vinyl-Fencing/Veranda/N-5yc1vZc3mqZ1ko?gclid=CJPlsvuonb4CFY17fgodegcAtA&cm_mmc=SEM|G|VF|D21|Fencing|Veranda&skwcid=AL!3360!3!20812166797!e!!g!!pvc%20privacy%20fence&ef_id=UaiJJwAAATqh@h2I:20140508215659:s)?

Comment: Post pic of the problem. Too many different types of fences and meanings of what a "plank" might mean.